# UITableView - how to recognize a deselection?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my app I want to have certain buttons that are inactive when there is no row selected in my table view. There is a method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, that tells me when a row was selected. Is there a way to know if a row was deselected?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method called `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` in `UITableView`.
You have to override it in a custom class to react on deselections.

See this [article](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cout << "selected Row: " << selectedRow << endl;
    } else {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cout << "deselected Row: " << selectedRow << endl;

    }
}
```

Is one way of visually and programmatically showing it.